# Regex match for beginning of multiple words in string

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript i want to be able to match strings that begin with a certain phrase.  However, I want it to be able to match the start of any word in the phrase, not just the beginning of the phrase.

For example:

Phrase: "This is the best"

Need to Match: "th"

Result: Matches Th and th

EDIT:  \b works great however it proposes another issue:

It will also match characters after foreign ones. For example if my string is "Männ", and i search for "n", it will match the n after Mä...Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
"This is the best moth".match(/\bth/gi);
```

or with a variable for your  string

```
var string = "This is the best moth";
alert(string.match(/\bth/gi));
```

`\b` in a regex is a word boundary so `\bth` will only match a `th` that at the beginning of a word.

`gi` is for a global match (look for all occurrences) and case insensitive

(I threw `moth` in there to as a reminder to check that it is not matched)

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/GNHX7/)

---

**Edit:**

So, the above only returns the part that you match (`th`). If you want to return the entire words, you have to match the entire word.

This is where things get tricky fast. First with no HTML entity letter:

```
string.match(/\bth[^\b]*?\b/gi);
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/BfQTX/)

To match the entire word go from the word boundary `\b` grab the `th` followed by non word boundaries `[^\b]` until you get to another word boundary `\b`. The `*` means you want to look for 0 or more of the previous (non word boundaries) the `?` mark means that this is a lazy match. In other words it doesn't expand to as big as would be possible, but stops at the first opportunity.

If you have HTML entity characters like ä (`&auml;`) things get complicated really fast, and you have to use whitespace or whitespace and a set of defined characters that may be at word boundaries.

```
string.match(/\sth[^\s]*|^th[^\s]*/gi);
```

[**Example with HTML entities.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pf5z9/)

Since we're not using word boundaries, we have to take care of the beginning of the string separately (`|^`).

The above will capture the white space at the beginning of words. Using `\b` will not capture white space, since `\b` has no width.

Comment: @Michael - YW! This is a great reference for regex - http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: This works great, except that it will also match characters after foreign ones. For example if my string is "Männ", and i search for "n", it will match the n after Mä...Any ideas?

Comment: @abadaba - Added the possibility of using `\s` to the answer.

Comment: But then this will only match words that begin with a space

Comment: Also, if the word matches anything following a space, can you have it so the array of matches returns the word without the space?

Comment: @abadaba - You use parentheses for that. Hang on, I'll edit it.

Comment: Hmm, but let's say if I have "The boat thought", if i match for "th", it will return ["Th"," th"] because it matches the space before thought.  How do i get it to return ["Th","th"] instead?

Comment: @abadaba - yes, that's true if you do not use `\b`. `\b` has no width, so it doesn't have the problem. Otherwise you have to use parentheses to match only the part you want.

Comment: Peter, your new example with:

"This is the best moth".match(/\s(th[^\s]*)|^(th[^\s]*)/gi);

still returns ["This", " the"]

Comment: @abadaba - hmmm... not sure what's going on - I'm looking through http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Comment: @abadaba - Pretty complicated if you want to ignore spaces and not use `\b` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508327/how-do-you-use-non-captured-elements-in-a-javascript-regex/3508365#3508365

Answer (score 2):

Use the `g` flag in the regex. It stands for "global", I think, and it searches for *all* matches instead of only the first one.

You should also use the `i` flag for case-insensitive matching.

You add flags to the end of the regex (`/<regex>/<flags>`)  or as a second parameter to `new RegExp(pattern, flags)`

For instance:

```
var matches = "This is the best".match(/\bth/gi);
```

or, using `RegExp` objects:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\bth", "gi");
var matches = re.exec("This is the best");
```

**EDIT:**
Use `\b` in the regex to match the **b**oundary of a word. Note that it does not really match any specific character, but the beginning or end of a word or the string.

Comment: But this will search in between words in the string which i don't want

Comment: This will also match `moth` in the string.

Comment: This will match all occurrences of 'th', whether they are at the start of a word or not.

Comment: abadaba: just use \b in the beginning of the regex. \b is for "boundary", which does not match any particular character, but it matches the beginning/end of a word and the string.

Comment: This works great, except that it will also match characters after foreign ones.

For example if my string is "Männ", and i search for "n", it will match the n after Mä...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
string.match(/^th|\sth/gi);
```

Examples:

```
'is this is a string'.match(/^th|\sth/gi);


'the string: This is a string'.match(/^th|\sth/gi);
```

Results:

> ["th", " Th"]
>
> ["th"]

Comment: Since op mentions, `any word` it may not be safe to assume a space for a word boundary. Your regex doesn't match anything in, `Here-is-the-sentence!`. This is why `\b` is better as a word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

```
var matches = "This is the best".match(/\bth/ig);
```

returns:

```
["Th", "th"]
```

The regular expression means: Match "th" ignoring case and globally (meaning, don't stop at just one match) if "th" is the first word in the string or if "th" is preceded by a space character.

Comment: Since op mentions, `any word` it may not be safe to assume a space for a word boundary. Your regex doesn't match anything in, `Here-is-the-sentence!`. This is why `\b` is better as a word boundary.

Comment: @Peter Thanks! Didn't know about `\b`!

Comment: @Vivn - Your example still only matches "Th" because of the beginning of line character `^`. A global search for the beginning of line on a string still only returns 1 find ;) - http://jsfiddle.net/NHcLx/