# How do you use non captured elements in a Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture `thing` in `nothing` globally and case insensitively.

For some reason this doesn't work:

```
"Nothing thing nothing".match(/no(thing)/gi);
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G7dkm/)

The captured array is `Nothing,nothing` instead of `thing,thing`.

I thought [**parentheses delimit the matching pattern**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)? What am I doing wrong?

(*yes, I know this will also match in `nothingness`*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the global flag, the [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_javascript_1.5_reference:objects:string:match) method will return all overall matches.  This is the equivalent of the first element of every match array you would get without global.

To get all groups from each match, loop:

```
var match;
while(match = /no(thing)/gi.exec("Nothing thing nothing")) 
{ 
  // Do something with match
}
```

This will give you `["Nothing", "thing"]` and `["nothing", "thing"]`.

Comment: Thanks. That does work, but for some reason, I just thought there was a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: Just reading Javascript: The Good Parts, and this is Crockford's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses or no, the whole of the matched substring is always captured--think of it as the default capturing group.  What the *explicit* capturing groups do is enable you to work with smaller chunks of text within the overall match.

The tutorial you linked to does indeed list the grouping constructs under the heading "pattern delimiters", but it's wrong, and the actual description isn't much better:

> `(pattern), (?:pattern)`      Matches entire contained pattern.

Well of course they're going to match it (or try to)!  But what the *parentheses* do is treat the entire contained **sub**pattern as a unit, so you can (for example) add a quantifier to it:

```
(?:foo){3}  // "foofoofoo"
```

`(?:...)` is a pure grouping construct, while `(...)` also captures whatever the contained subpattern matches.

With just a quick look-through I spotted several more examples of inaccurate, ambiguous, or incomplete descriptions.  I suggest you unbookmark that tutorial immediately and bookmark this one instead: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses do nothing in this regex.

The regex `/no(thing)/gi` is same as `/nothing/gi`.

Parentheses are used for grouping. If you don't put any reference to groups (using $1, $2) or count for group, the () are useless.

So, this regex will find only this sequence n-o-t-h-i-n-g. The word `thing` does'nt starts with 'no', so it doen't match.

---

**EDIT:**

Change to `/(no)?thing/gi` and will work.
Will work because ()? indicates a optional part.

Comment: Ok, so how **do** you find `thing` in `nothing` ;) (downvote not mine, btw)

Comment: Sorry. I read in the question "thing AND nothing", not "thing IN nothing". So you want thing INSIDE nothing. Now I understand.