# Regular expression start with specific letter

Tags: regex

I am using this `^[S-s][0-9]{4}$` to validate my string, but not working properly. my string has to be in the form of the Letter `S` (upper-case or lower-case) followed by 4 digits, e.g. `S1234`. Looks like it works for Letters above S, meaning if I enter `w1234` it validates correct, but if I enter a letter below s, like `a1234` it doesn’t validate.  Thanks.

Comment: That sounds backward.  `[S-s]` is equivalent to ```[STUVWXYZ\[\\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrs]```.  I would expect it to match `a` or `W`, but not `A` or `w`.

Comment: Thanks for the note, now i understand why it was matching letters above s.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to get rid of the dash:

```
^[Ss][0-9]{4}$
```

dashes within `[...]` denote character ranges. Thus `S-s` in regex would mean "every character in Unicode character table between S and s" and as those two are not adjacent, you end up with a bunch of matched chars.

Comment: alter it to ^[S-Zs-z]  i think the question was edited on you.

Comment: ^[Ss][0-9]{4}$ works for me. I just wanted the first letter to be S(small or big).

Answer (score 2):

Not answer directly the detail content of the question, but whom who end up to this question by the question's title and looking for the answer of regex to find match words begin with specific letter like :
`This is a` **Zone**
You should use this regex:

```
\bd[a-zA-Z]+
```

`[a-zA-Z]` should replace by the expected tail you want.
Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507453/regex-match-for-beginning-of-multiple-words-in-string)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: yeah, just edit the answer, not directly for the question detail, but for someone search on google and landed here by the title, this might help since I was the guy like that.

Answer (score 0):

`[S-s]` means the range of all characters between capital S and lowercase s. Try `^[Ss][0-9]{4}$` instead. Or better yet, `^s\d{4}$` with a case-insensitivity modifier (`/i` in many languages).